# Snowflake to SQL Server data load performance

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-server-2016, database-performance, linked-server

I am trying to improve performance of a SQL query used to move data from snowflake view to SQL Server table. Query uses linked server created using a ODBC driver to connect to Snowflake view from SQL Server using an `OPENQUERY` statement. Currently 50 million rows take around 2 hours to move the data. Please suggest if there is anything that can be done to improve performance.

Sample query we are using:

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM OPENQUERY (SnowflakeServer, 'select * from "SnowflakeDB"."SnowflakeSchema"."mytable"')
```

Comment: never use snowflake but I will do the same and report the migration take long time because the data is so Big

Answer (score 0):

So this is not based on anything concrete, but a few ideas could be.

1. Importing to a table with an columnstore index
2. Doing the [query using PolyBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-odbc-generic?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. Exporting your query to CSV and loading using [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#input-file-format-options)